# .htaccess url rewrite for POST request

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'data.php',
    data: {
        cc: cc,
        mobile: mobile,
        captcha: captcha
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I want to use url: `/signup`,  instead of `data.php`. How to achieve it using `.htaccess` rewrite.
Please help I have tried this in my `.htacceess` file
`RewriteRule ^signup/?$ /data.php [L]` 
but it is throwing error `404`.

Answer (score 2):

The following `RewriteRule` should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule signup data.php
```

If you did not enable override, you have to change it

> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Change the `AllowOverride` None to `AllowOverride All`

And the AJAX URL can be

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/signup',
       data: {cc: cc, mobile: mobile, captcha: captcha
    },
    success: function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check your apache configuration whether it is enable or not.

Comment: other rewrite rules are working perfectly fine,those are for GET request.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help me sove this problem but sorry, i am new to .htaccess and i didn't understood what you have tried to explain me. Can u elaborate it and where and how should i do this.

Comment: I am on a shared hosting so i cant change apache configuration file. Any alternative to this?